# Slide down modal navigation

Tags: ios

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a button. On the click of the button, it transitions as a `modal` (slide up transition) to a `TabViewController` which has two tab items.

On both the tab items, I have a Close button on which I want to transition back to the `UIViewController` mentioned above but in a slide-down transition.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the view controllers with the close button, call this when the button's `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event is raised:

```
[self.parentViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us say, you have button close target as `dismissMe`,

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 75);
button.titleLabel.text = @"Close";
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
button.center = self.view.center;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

then please add the following code to target method.

```
-(void)dismissMe {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also you can use this instead

```
[self.parentViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```